# Microsoft.Interop.Office.Word full style not applying

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am trying to produce edit a word document using `Microsoft.Interop.Office.Word`, and am using the

```
Range.set_style(String style)
```

method.

I am using the method to apply a custom style that is in the document called `"Req Level 1."` It has a different text size, is bold, has a font, and has a numbering system.

Req level 1 would have one number:

3

Req level 2 would have two numbers:

3.1

Req level 3 would have three numbers:

3.1.1

and so on.

My problem is that whenever I apply the styles, the numbering is lost. The bold, the proper size, and the font are all correct, implying that each style is being set correctly, but the numbering does not appear.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your Req Level 1 style
Style based on (no style)

Create Req Level 2 style
Style based on Req Level 1

Click on [image]

Multilevel list

Define a new list style

[image: New list style]

Click on Format Numbering 
[image: Format numbering]
Click on the more button
Link level to Req Level 1
Click on level 2 and link to Req Level 2
[image: Level 2]
Delete everything in the Number Format box
Select dropdown from include level from and include number from level 1
In the number format box add a fullstop and then select 1, 2, 3,... from the
Number style for this level box
Repeat for as many levels as you need
This post is really helpful, http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html

Once you have the levels set up adding them is quite easy using the `Range.set_style(String style)` method